Vertical Resource View with events from multiple Google Calendar
I am trying to create a Vertical Resource View (1-day vertical resource view) with events from multiple Google Calendars.
To do this, the events from a single Google Calendar each represent a resource. All Google Calendars come from a single Google Account, so only one API key. I have currently integrated these as described in the documentation:
googleCalendarApiKey: 'api-key',

eventSources: [
  { // Room Alpha
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-alpha@group.calendar.google.com',
    backgroundColor: '#8ecae6'
  },
  { // Room Bravo
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-bravo@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#219ebc'
  },
  { // Room Charlie
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-charlie@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#023047'
  },
  { // Room Delta
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-delta@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#ffb703'
  },
  { // Room Echo
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-echo@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#fb8500'
  }
],

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to provide the events from the Google calendars for the individual rooms. According to the documentation, it should look like this:
initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
resources: [
  { id: 'a', title: 'Room Alpha' },
  { id: 'b', title: 'Room Bravo' },
  { id: 'c', title: 'Room Charlie' },
  { id: 'c', title: 'Room Delta' },
  { id: 'd', title: 'Room Echo' }
],

So I tried to replace id: with the googleCalendarId:, both the content and the element, but that didn't work.
I couldn't find anything else in the documentation. I have not found a useful approach in other ways either. I hope someone here can help me.
Thank you very much.

Your resource list is fine, but the problem will be that the events themselves don't contain a resource ID when they are fetched from the Google Calendar - because the calendar has no concept of "resources"...instead you've used different calendars to represent the different rooms. Therefore fullCalendar can't match the event to a specific resource, in order to know where to display it.
You can overcome this by adding a per-event-source data transform. The event source documentation notes that you can add an eventDataTransform callback specifically for that source. The eventDataTransform callback allows you to manipulate the data of each event after it's been downloaded from the source, but before it's passed to fullCalendar's rendering functionality.
You can use that to add the relevant resource ID to each downloaded event, in order to map the Google Calendar rooms to a fullCalendar resource.
For example:
initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
resources: [
  { id: 'a', title: 'Room Alpha' },
  { id: 'b', title: 'Room Bravo' },
  { id: 'c', title: 'Room Charlie' },
  { id: 'c', title: 'Room Delta' },
  { id: 'd', title: 'Room Echo' }
],
googleCalendarApiKey: 'api-key',
eventSources: [
  { // Room Alpha
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-alpha@group.calendar.google.com',
    backgroundColor: '#8ecae6',
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData)
    {
      eventData.resourceId = 'a';
      return eventData;
    }
  },
  { // Room Bravo
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-bravo@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#219ebc',
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData)
    {
      eventData.resourceId = 'b';
      return eventData;
    }  },
  { // Room Charlie
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-charlie@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#023047',
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData)
    {
      eventData.resourceId = 'c';
      return eventData;
    }
  },
  { // Room Delta
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-delta@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#ffb703',
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData)
    {
      eventData.resourceId = 'd';
      return eventData;
    }
  },
  { // Room Echo
    googleCalendarId: 'calendar-id-room-echo@group.calendar.google.com',  
    backgroundColor: '#fb8500',
    eventDataTransform: function(eventData)
    {
      eventData.resourceId = 'e';
      return eventData;
    }
  }
],

